# Potential Leak of An Object Using Xcode with ARC

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, crash-reports

I have an application in Xcode 4.5.2 and I am using ARC.  My application has been building and running without complier warnings or errors, however, when the application goes into the background and then returns to the foreground (particularly after an extended period of time has passed in between), the app crashes.  I am fairly new to iOS and I have been trying endlessly to analyze crash reports, and symbolicate the crashes, but I have been unsuccessful in gleaning any clues to the problem thus far. However, all of a sudden when I re-opened my project, a line of code (that has been there all along) now shows a **blue compiler warning:Memory (Core Foundation/Objective C) Potential Leak of an Object.**  I don't understand why this piece of code is generating this warning in the context of using ARC, nor do I understand why it suddenly appeared. I am assuming this may be related to the crash issue, but I have no idea why I am getting this error thus I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the code where the problem is located:

```
- (void) cropPhoto:(UIImage *)originalImage inImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView atXPoint:(int)x atYPoint:(int)y withWidthSize:(int)width withHeightSize:(int)height
{
  CGSize size = [originalImage size]; //gets size of Facebook photo

  [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)]; 

  [self.view addSubview:imageView]; //adds imageView to view

  CGRect rect = CGRectMake (size.width / 4, size.height / 4 ,
                          (size.width / 1), (size.height / 2));

  //THIS NEXT LINE GIVES THE COMPILER WARNING!!
  [imageView setImage:[UIImage    
        imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([originalImage CGImage], rect)]]; 

  [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
  [self.view addSubview:imageView];

}
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()` returns an object you must release. (It has a retain count of 1)

ARC doesn't handle retain/release of Core Foundation objects for you.

Your code should look like this:

```
{
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([originalImage CGImage], rect)
    [ imageView setImage:[ UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage ] ] ;
    CGImageRelease( cgImage ) ;
}
```

EDIT:

Here's another option:

```
[imageView setImage:[UIImage    
    imageWithCGImage:CFBridgingRelease( CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([originalImage CGImage], rect))]];
```